# R data.table: optimize speed of row operations by (different) groups

Tags: r, optimization, datatable, data.table, self-join

So, I have this huge data set (possibly thousands of entries) that is received by my code as a data.table in long format, that looks like this:

```
#sample DT
sample_size = 8
DT0 <- data.table(
  DATE = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020/3/01"), by = "day", length.out = sample_size),
  BANANA = seq(30, by=0.060, length.out = sample_size),
  ORANGE = seq(5, by=0.035, length.out = sample_size),
  APPLE = seq(12, by=0.6, length.out = sample_size),
  LEMON = seq(10, by=0.01, length.out = sample_size),
  GRAPE = seq(0.5, by=0.13, length.out = sample_size)
)

DT <- melt(DT0, 
           id.vars = c("DATE"), 
           variable.name = "FRUIT",
           value.name = "PRICE")
setkeyv(DT, cols=c("FRUIT", "DATE"))
```

DT is exactly how my data looks like right now:

```
> DT
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE
 1: 2020-03-01 BANANA 30.000
 2: 2020-03-02 BANANA 30.060
 3: 2020-03-03 BANANA 30.120
 4: 2020-03-04 BANANA 30.180
 5: 2020-03-05 BANANA 30.240
 6: 2020-03-06 BANANA 30.300
 7: 2020-03-07 BANANA 30.360
 8: 2020-03-08 BANANA 30.420
 9: 2020-03-01 ORANGE  5.000
10: 2020-03-02 ORANGE  5.035
11: 2020-03-03 ORANGE  5.070
12: 2020-03-04 ORANGE  5.105
13: 2020-03-05 ORANGE  5.140
14: 2020-03-06 ORANGE  5.175
15: 2020-03-07 ORANGE  5.210
16: 2020-03-08 ORANGE  5.245
17: 2020-03-01  APPLE 12.000
18: 2020-03-02  APPLE 12.600
19: 2020-03-03  APPLE 13.200
20: 2020-03-04  APPLE 13.800
21: 2020-03-05  APPLE 14.400
22: 2020-03-06  APPLE 15.000
23: 2020-03-07  APPLE 15.600
24: 2020-03-08  APPLE 16.200
25: 2020-03-01  LEMON 10.000
26: 2020-03-02  LEMON 10.010
27: 2020-03-03  LEMON 10.020
28: 2020-03-04  LEMON 10.030
29: 2020-03-05  LEMON 10.040
30: 2020-03-06  LEMON 10.050
31: 2020-03-07  LEMON 10.060
32: 2020-03-08  LEMON 10.070
33: 2020-03-01  GRAPE  0.500
34: 2020-03-02  GRAPE  0.630
35: 2020-03-03  GRAPE  0.760
36: 2020-03-04  GRAPE  0.890
37: 2020-03-05  GRAPE  1.020
38: 2020-03-06  GRAPE  1.150
39: 2020-03-07  GRAPE  1.280
40: 2020-03-08  GRAPE  1.410
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE
```

Now, let's say that I need to compute in a new column ("RESULT"), the difference ( or any other more complex operation) between the PRICE of each of the items in FRUIT and the price of one constant specified fruit (ex: GRAPE), for each day.

Just to help you visualize the idea, the RESULT column would be something like as the result of these operations, for each day:

> result := PRICE BANANA - PRICE GRAPE
> result := PRICE ORANGE - PRICE GRAPE
> result := PRICE APPLE - PRICE GRAPE
> result := PRICE BANANA - PRICE GRAPE
> result := PRICE LEMON - PRICE GRAPE
> result := PRICE GRAPE - PRICE GRAPE

And here's how I managed to do it, after many hours of trial and error (and still not quite understanding what I'm doing):

```
#my try:
chosen_fruit <- "GRAPE"

setkey(DT, DATE)
DT[DT[FRUIT == chosen_fruit], RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE]
```

```
> DT
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE RESULTS
 1: 2020-03-01 BANANA 30.000  29.500
 2: 2020-03-01 ORANGE  5.000   4.500
 3: 2020-03-01  APPLE 12.000  11.500
 4: 2020-03-01  LEMON 10.000   9.500
 5: 2020-03-01  GRAPE  0.500   0.000
 6: 2020-03-02 BANANA 30.060  29.430
 7: 2020-03-02 ORANGE  5.035   4.405
 8: 2020-03-02  APPLE 12.600  11.970
 9: 2020-03-02  LEMON 10.010   9.380
10: 2020-03-02  GRAPE  0.630   0.000
11: 2020-03-03 BANANA 30.120  29.360
12: 2020-03-03 ORANGE  5.070   4.310
13: 2020-03-03  APPLE 13.200  12.440
14: 2020-03-03  LEMON 10.020   9.260
15: 2020-03-03  GRAPE  0.760   0.000
16: 2020-03-04 BANANA 30.180  29.290
17: 2020-03-04 ORANGE  5.105   4.215
18: 2020-03-04  APPLE 13.800  12.910
19: 2020-03-04  LEMON 10.030   9.140
20: 2020-03-04  GRAPE  0.890   0.000
21: 2020-03-05 BANANA 30.240  29.220
22: 2020-03-05 ORANGE  5.140   4.120
23: 2020-03-05  APPLE 14.400  13.380
24: 2020-03-05  LEMON 10.040   9.020
25: 2020-03-05  GRAPE  1.020   0.000
26: 2020-03-06 BANANA 30.300  29.150
27: 2020-03-06 ORANGE  5.175   4.025
28: 2020-03-06  APPLE 15.000  13.850
29: 2020-03-06  LEMON 10.050   8.900
30: 2020-03-06  GRAPE  1.150   0.000
31: 2020-03-07 BANANA 30.360  29.080
32: 2020-03-07 ORANGE  5.210   3.930
33: 2020-03-07  APPLE 15.600  14.320
34: 2020-03-07  LEMON 10.060   8.780
35: 2020-03-07  GRAPE  1.280   0.000
36: 2020-03-08 BANANA 30.420  29.010
37: 2020-03-08 ORANGE  5.245   3.835
38: 2020-03-08  APPLE 16.200  14.790
39: 2020-03-08  LEMON 10.070   8.660
40: 2020-03-08  GRAPE  1.410   0.000
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE RESULTS
```

And my final desired output:

```
setkey(DT, FRUIT)

> DT
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE RESULTS
 1: 2020-03-01 BANANA 30.000  29.500
 2: 2020-03-02 BANANA 30.060  29.430
 3: 2020-03-03 BANANA 30.120  29.360
 4: 2020-03-04 BANANA 30.180  29.290
 5: 2020-03-05 BANANA 30.240  29.220
 6: 2020-03-06 BANANA 30.300  29.150
 7: 2020-03-07 BANANA 30.360  29.080
 8: 2020-03-08 BANANA 30.420  29.010
 9: 2020-03-01 ORANGE  5.000   4.500
10: 2020-03-02 ORANGE  5.035   4.405
11: 2020-03-03 ORANGE  5.070   4.310
12: 2020-03-04 ORANGE  5.105   4.215
13: 2020-03-05 ORANGE  5.140   4.120
14: 2020-03-06 ORANGE  5.175   4.025
15: 2020-03-07 ORANGE  5.210   3.930
16: 2020-03-08 ORANGE  5.245   3.835
17: 2020-03-01  APPLE 12.000  11.500
18: 2020-03-02  APPLE 12.600  11.970
19: 2020-03-03  APPLE 13.200  12.440
20: 2020-03-04  APPLE 13.800  12.910
21: 2020-03-05  APPLE 14.400  13.380
22: 2020-03-06  APPLE 15.000  13.850
23: 2020-03-07  APPLE 15.600  14.320
24: 2020-03-08  APPLE 16.200  14.790
25: 2020-03-01  LEMON 10.000   9.500
26: 2020-03-02  LEMON 10.010   9.380
27: 2020-03-03  LEMON 10.020   9.260
28: 2020-03-04  LEMON 10.030   9.140
29: 2020-03-05  LEMON 10.040   9.020
30: 2020-03-06  LEMON 10.050   8.900
31: 2020-03-07  LEMON 10.060   8.780
32: 2020-03-08  LEMON 10.070   8.660
33: 2020-03-01  GRAPE  0.500   0.000
34: 2020-03-02  GRAPE  0.630   0.000
35: 2020-03-03  GRAPE  0.760   0.000
36: 2020-03-04  GRAPE  0.890   0.000
37: 2020-03-05  GRAPE  1.020   0.000
38: 2020-03-06  GRAPE  1.150   0.000
39: 2020-03-07  GRAPE  1.280   0.000
40: 2020-03-08  GRAPE  1.410   0.000
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE RESULTS
```

As you can see, I was, somehow, able to reach the target. But it doesn't seem ideal.

I'm learning R (and programming in general) now, so I am VERY new to all of this, especially in making the code as optimized as possible (consider memory constraints here).

Any suggestions on how to improve the speed/performance of operation or better ways to do that?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think that is a very reasonable way to perform the calculation you want to do. You are performing a join on the columns `FRUIT` and `DATE` because you previously set the keys for `DT` and joins happen on the keys by default. The column `PRICE.i` is the price from the subset copy of `DT` because it is in the `i` position of `DT[i,j]`. Hopefully someone will come along and do a benchmark to see if your join version is faster than akrun's `by = ` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, we don't need the `==` once we `set` the key i.e. the first `setkey` is enough, and join `on` by 'DATE' while doing the subtraction of `PRICE` and `i.PRICE`

```
setkeyv(DT, cols=c("FRUIT", "DATE"))
DT[DT[.(chosen_fruit)],  RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE, on = .(DATE)]
```

---

Or another option is do a group by 'DATE', subtract the 'PRICE' from the corresponding PRICE where 'FRUIT' is 'GRAPE'

```
library(data.table)
DT[, RESULTS := PRICE - PRICE[FRUIT == 'GRAPE'], DATE]
```

-output

```
DT
          DATE  FRUIT  PRICE RESULTS
 1: 2020-03-01 BANANA 30.000  29.500
 2: 2020-03-02 BANANA 30.060  29.430
 3: 2020-03-03 BANANA 30.120  29.360
 4: 2020-03-04 BANANA 30.180  29.290
 5: 2020-03-05 BANANA 30.240  29.220
 6: 2020-03-06 BANANA 30.300  29.150
 7: 2020-03-07 BANANA 30.360  29.080
 8: 2020-03-08 BANANA 30.420  29.010
 9: 2020-03-01 ORANGE  5.000   4.500
10: 2020-03-02 ORANGE  5.035   4.405
11: 2020-03-03 ORANGE  5.070   4.310
12: 2020-03-04 ORANGE  5.105   4.215
13: 2020-03-05 ORANGE  5.140   4.120
14: 2020-03-06 ORANGE  5.175   4.025
15: 2020-03-07 ORANGE  5.210   3.930
16: 2020-03-08 ORANGE  5.245   3.835
17: 2020-03-01  APPLE 12.000  11.500
18: 2020-03-02  APPLE 12.600  11.970
19: 2020-03-03  APPLE 13.200  12.440
20: 2020-03-04  APPLE 13.800  12.910
21: 2020-03-05  APPLE 14.400  13.380
22: 2020-03-06  APPLE 15.000  13.850
23: 2020-03-07  APPLE 15.600  14.320
24: 2020-03-08  APPLE 16.200  14.790
25: 2020-03-01  LEMON 10.000   9.500
26: 2020-03-02  LEMON 10.010   9.380
27: 2020-03-03  LEMON 10.020   9.260
28: 2020-03-04  LEMON 10.030   9.140
29: 2020-03-05  LEMON 10.040   9.020
30: 2020-03-06  LEMON 10.050   8.900
31: 2020-03-07  LEMON 10.060   8.780
32: 2020-03-08  LEMON 10.070   8.660
33: 2020-03-01  GRAPE  0.500   0.000
34: 2020-03-02  GRAPE  0.630   0.000
35: 2020-03-03  GRAPE  0.760   0.000
36: 2020-03-04  GRAPE  0.890   0.000
37: 2020-03-05  GRAPE  1.020   0.000
38: 2020-03-06  GRAPE  1.150   0.000
39: 2020-03-07  GRAPE  1.280   0.000
40: 2020-03-08  GRAPE  1.410   0.000
```

---

Or another option is to `dcast` to 'wide' format and then do the subtraction

```
dt_wide <- dcast(DT, DATE ~ FRUIT, value.var = 'PRICE')
nm1 <- names(dt_wide)[-1]
dt_wide[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - GRAPE), .SDcols = nm1]
```

#### Benchmarks

Tested on a slightly bigger dataset by changing the `sample_size` in constructing the input data

```
sample_size <- 1000000
dim(DT)
#[1] 5000000       3



system.time(DT[DT[.(chosen_fruit)],  RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE, on = .(DATE)])
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.287   0.039   0.326 

system.time({     DT[DT[FRUIT == chosen_fruit], RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE, on = .(DATE)] })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.294   0.006   0.300 

system.time({
  setkey(DT, DATE)
  DT[DT[FRUIT == chosen_fruit], RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE]
  setkey(DT, FRUIT)
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.431   0.045   0.476 


system.time(DT[, RESULTS := PRICE - PRICE[FRUIT == 'GRAPE'], DATE])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  6.660   0.039   6.665 

system.time({
dt_wide <- dcast(DT, DATE ~ FRUIT, value.var = 'PRICE')
nm1 <- names(dt_wide)[-1]
dt_wide[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - GRAPE), .SDcols = nm1]

})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.868   0.060   0.926
```

Comment: Do the two ways have improved speed compared to OP's code?

Comment: @mt1022 you can check the benchmarks updated

Comment: I was surprised that `PRICE - PRICE[FRUIT == 'GRAPE']` is much slower than other ways. And the slightly longer execution time of OP's code in your benchmark might be caused by the two `setkey` operations. Besides the use of `DT[.(chosen_fruit)]` doesn't improve the speed. You can try to benchmark `system.time({
    DT[DT[FRUIT == chosen_fruit], RESULTS := PRICE - i.PRICE, on = .(DATE)]
})`.

Comment: @mt1022 In my system, it is showing `0.294` against `0.287`.  I would say that the OP doesn't need the two `setkey` operations instead can do the first option in my code

Comment: That's almost the same, compared to the one with two `setkey`. The efficiency is due to not using `setkey`.

Comment: @mt1022 my point is that you can get the same efficiency with less code